# Does Amazon SQS Extended Client Library support zipping of uploaded file in S3?

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to figure out if Amazon SQS Extended Client Library supports zipping of uploaded file in S3. I Googled quite a lot but found no evidence of such support. The idea is to tell SQS in the message request to store in S3 as a Zip. So looking in the Java example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html , it would be something like sqsExtended.sendMessage(myMessageRequest, true /*a parameter telling to zip the file in S3*/);
This example is in Java but I know there are implementations of the extended client library also for Nodejs and python.
Does anyone know if there is such support or if such support is intended to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring the source code for AmazonSQSExtendedClient at https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/AmazonSQSExtendedClient.java it turns out that it uses PayloadStore - https://github.com/awslabs/payload-offloading-java-common-lib-for-aws/blob/master/src/main/java/software/amazon/payloadoffloading/PayloadStore.java
The interface method storeOriginalPayload has no parameter for setting zip behavior. The implementing class S3BackedPayloadStore does not show any evidence of zipping either. So my conclusion is that this functionality is currently not implemented.